# Oracle merge sql doesn't work when update with where condtions

Tags: oracle, oracle9i, sql-merge

My problem is that an error occurred when I update with where conditions.

The error message is 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"

If I remove this line  `where q1.SALE_QTY <> -9` , then that sql works.

Database version : oracle 9i
SQL:

```
merge into TBL_QTY q1
using (
select 'A111' as prod_no
       ,'BAT0000171624' as part_batch_no
       ,'172' as cond1_type
       ,'20201225' as beg_dt  
      ,'20201225' as end_dt
      , 17 as obtain_qty
      , 17 as sale_qty ) q2
      on　
(  q1.PROD_NO = q2.PROD_NO
  and q1.PART_BATCH_NO = q2.PART_BATCH_NO
  and q1.COND1_TYPE = q2.COND1_TYPE
  and q1.BEG_DT = q2.BEG_DT
  and q1.END_DT= q2.END_DT)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   update  SET q1.OBTAIN_QTY    = 15     
               ,q1.SALE_QTY      = 15 
               where q1.SALE_QTY <> -9
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (PROD_NO, PART_BATCH_NO, COND1_TYPE, BEG_DT
           ,END_DT , OBTAIN_QTY   , SALE_QTY           )
   VALUES (q2.PROD_NO, q2.PART_BATCH_NO, q2.COND1_TYPE, q2.BEG_DT
           ,q2.END_DT , q2.OBTAIN_QTY   , q2.SALE_QTY           );
```

Comment: The `merge` statement simply didn't support a `WHERE` clause in the UPDATE part in Oracle 9 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/statements_915a.htm#2084365

Comment: Thank you!! Is there any way can help to achieve my purpose? To update with conditions.

Comment: One option is to use separate UPDATE and INSERT statements.

Comment: Oracle 10g have the option to use WHERE clause with merge statement. You can refer - https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/merge-enhancements-10g. So another option is to have upgraded version Since 9i is too old to use now.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: "*Since 9i is too old to use now*" - and so is Oracle 10 (and 11)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I meant to say that, Oracle 10g have introduced the usage of where clause in merge statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve the same behavior is to use `CASE..WHEN` as follows in `UPDATE` clause of the `MERGE` statement.

```
...
...
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   update  SET q1.OBTAIN_QTY = CASE WHEN q1.SALE_QTY <> -9 THEN 15 ELSE q1.OBTAIN_QTY END
               ,q1.SALE_QTY  = CASE WHEN q1.SALE_QTY <> -9 THEN 15 ELSE q1.SALE_QTY END
              -- where q1.SALE_QTY <> -9
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
...
...
```

Cheers!!

Comment: it almost achieves my purpose. But when the case not in "case when", there will be an  "cannot udpate to null" error.  Actually I want is that do nothing  when qty != -9